# What is a relatively simple/heuristic formula to find the yield of an explosive given the peak overpressure and the mass of the charge?

Tags: explosions, shock-waves

Suppose one can experimentally determine the two parameters mentioned in the question, are they enough for a good approximation of the yield of the explosive? I am thinking there are some ways to do so by considering other important parameters as being aprroximaed by some constant but I am by no means well versed in the physics of explosives.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the "Los Alamos primer" that talks a little bit about how the pressure varies as a function of the radius of the blast.

Indeed, they show an equation that relates the maximum pressure at the wavefront $p$ and the total energy $E$ released :
$$ p = \frac{E}{r^3}$$

Knowing that a kg of TNT releases about $4\cdot 10^6$ J, you can find the mass of explosives needed to obtain an explosion of energy E. I didn't find a precise resource on explosion physics. If anyone knows of any, they would be most welcome.

Comment: It's basically just dimensional analysis: pressure has the same dimensions as energy/volume, and has about the same magnitude in plasma.

Comment: Oh that is so intuitively obvious now that I see it in front of my eyes. Now the question is just what factors should we include in the formula for a more precise approximation?

Comment: Famously, [Fermi made a "Fermi estimate" of the Trinity yield](https://www.atomicarchive.com/resources/documents/trinity/fermi.html) by dropping some pieces of paper and seeing how far they were deflected by the shockwave as it passed.  He estimated it at about 10 kt of TNT (the actual figure was about 18.6 kt).